# Find list of primary numbers that will be the multiplication of number

Tags: python, list, loops, recursion, time-complexity

Let us say we have list:

```
lst = [2,3,5,7]

num = 40
```

I have to receive `[2,2,2,5]` in order to find `40`.
Max time complexity ***O(sqrt(n))***
so what I did:

1. Built a function which will run through range of `((num ** 0.5) + 1)` and return that list
2. Built a function that will tell if a number is primary.
3. Built a function that receives the list from 1 and return a list of only primarys.
4. The main function, here is the problem.
   I dont know how to run through the list to receive all combination of reach target num(=40)
   I have to find like `[2,2,2,2], [2,2,2,3], [2,2,2,5],....,[3,3,3,3],...,[5,5,5,5],...,[7,7,7,7]`
   and find the one combination to actually reach 40.
   I thought about doing it recursively, but I dont know if the function will still be **O(sqrt(n))** and how to do it so...

**Mentioning, this problem is solved with iterator\Generator.
But since we have not learned generator ( Yield ) or iterator (if it isnt loops, so no idea what it is ), I cant use them.

I actually have the solution, but it is with generator, thus, problematic**

Edit:
I know how to do it with a known list, for example, something I solved:

```
def ABC(num,tempComb,new_list):
    if num == 0:    
        new_list.append(temp_combi)
        return new_list
    lst = ["A","B","C"]
    take_1=ABC(num-1,tempComb+[lst[0]],new_list)
    take_2=ABC(num-1,tempComb+[lst[1]],new_list)
    take_3=ABC(num-1,tempComb+[lst[2]],new_list)
    return take_1 + take_2 + take_3
```

Will return me combination from AAA to CCC
but in unknownlist, I dont know how to do it...

EDIT: apperantly this question has a specific name in english: Prime factorization.
This is the code that is working:

```
def prime_components(num): # 40
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i <= num:
        if (num % i) == 0:
            factors.append(i)
            num = num / i
        else:    
            i = i + 1
    return factors
```

***If people see this, case is answered and can be locked because its a duplicate***

Comment: You can turn a generator into a method that just returns its result set all at once, rather than one by one (based on your comment about having a solution that uses generators).

Comment: But as said in the post, I am not allowed to use generator, we have not learned it.

Comment: Yes, except you could modify the code to _not be a generator_, was my point. You basically replace the `yield` statement with adding the result to a list or other container, and then instead of raising `StopIteration`, you return the list.

Comment: Yea but I dont know what is generator, which is the problem.
But it is all good, I got the solution, added an edit.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun way using streams. `numbers` is an infinite stream of natural numbers starting at `n` -

```py
def numbers(n = 0):
  return stream(n, lambda:numbers(n + 1))
```

To construct a `stream`, we provide a value, `n` in this case, and a function to compute the remainder of the stream, `numbers(n + 1)` in this case. The key idea here is the "tail" of a stream can be another stream, and may continue infinitely, or may terminate with `None`.

`primes` can be defined as a stream of numbers starting at `2`, where all subsequent values do not contain previous values as factors. This technique is known as the *Sieve of Eratosthenes* -

```py
def primes(s = numbers(2)):
  return stream(s.value, lambda:primes(filter(s.next, lambda v: v % s.value != 0)))
```

This relies on a generic stream function `filter`, which creates a new stream that only includes values that pass the predicate function, `func` -

```py
def filter(s, func):
  if s:
    if func(s.value) == True:
      return stream(s.value, lambda:filter(s.next, func))
    else:
      return filter(s.next, func)
```

To create the `factors` of an intenger `n`, we use a stream of prime numbers `p` -

```py
def factors(n, p):
  if n > 0:
    if n % p.value == 0:
      return stream(p.value, lambda:factors(n // p.value, p))
    elif p.value ** 2 < n:
      return factors(n, p.next)
    else:
      return stream(n)
```

Finally we create `stream` -

```py
class stream:
  def __init__(self, value, then = lambda:None):
    self.value = value
    self.then = thunk(then)
  @property
  def next(self):
    return self.then()
  def __iter__(self):
    while self:
      yield self.value
      self = self.next
```

Which is an abstraction around `thunk` -

```py
class thunk:
  def __init__(self, compute):
    self.compute = compute
    self.value = self
  def __call__(self):
    if self.value is self:
      self.value = self.compute()
    return self.value
```

We'll run some tests -

```py
p = primes()

print(list(factors(51, p)))
# [3, 17]

print(list(factors(40, p)))
# [2, 2, 2, 5]

print(list(factors(84, p)))
# [2, 2, 3, 7]

print(list(factors(2959521755984640, p)))
# [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 7, 7, 11, 17, 19, 31, 41, 43]
```

Comment: God lord, I havent learned anything here :\
Not lambda, not stream, not thunk, not filter
But thanks, its good for people who know those stuff.
Thanks for sharing :)